# An interesting pattern in the general solution of the $n$-th order ODE: $\frac{d^n y}{dx^n}+\alpha x\frac{dy}{dx}+\beta y=0$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

**Context:**

My friend (The same one who gave me [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188299/solving-a-second-order-linear-ode-fracd2-ydx2x1-cdot-fracdydx) ODE) originally challenged me to obtain the general solution to this ODE:
$$\frac{d^3 y}{dx^3}+\alpha x\frac{dy}{dx}+\beta y=0 \tag{1}$$
Where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

I could not figure out any substitution without the use of power series. I thus decided to play around with [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), and decided to generalize the order of the ODE, like this:

> $$\frac{d^n y}{dx^n}+\alpha x\frac{dy}{dx}+\beta y=0 \tag{2}$$

Upon increasing the value of $n$, I noticed an interesting pattern:

When $n=3$, the [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27%2Ba*x*y%27%2Bb*y%3D0) is:
$$\small y(x)=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\alpha}\cdot c_2 x \cdot {_1F_2}\left(\frac{\beta}{3\alpha}+\frac{1}{3};\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3}; -\frac{x^3 \alpha}{9}\right)}{3^{2/3}}+c_1\cdot {_1F_2}\left(\frac{\beta}{3\alpha};\frac{1}{3};\frac{2}{3};-\frac{x^3\alpha}{9}\right)+\frac{\alpha^{2/3} c_3 x^2\cdot {_1F_2}\left(\frac{\beta}{3\alpha}+\frac{2}{3};\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3};-\frac{x^3 \alpha}{9}\right)}{\sqrt[3]{3}} \tag{3}$$
When $n=4$, the [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27%27%2Ba*x*y%27%2Bb*y%3D0) is:
$$\small y(x)=\frac{\sqrt[4]{\alpha}c_2 \cdot {_1F_3}\left(\frac{\beta}{4\alpha}+\frac{1}{4};\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};-\frac{x^4\alpha}{64}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+c_1\cdot {_1 F_3}\left(\frac{\beta}{4\alpha};\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};-\frac{x^4 \alpha}{64}\right)+\frac{\alpha^{3/4} c_4 x^3\cdot {_1F_3}\left(\frac{\beta}{4\alpha}+\frac{3}{4};\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2},\frac{7}{4};-\frac{x^4 \alpha}{64}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{\alpha}c_3 x^2 {_1F_3}\left(\frac{\beta}{4\alpha}+\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2};-\frac{x^4 \alpha}{64}\right)$$
When $n=5$, the [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27%27%27%2Ba*x*y%27%2Bb*y%3D0) is:
$$\small y(x)=\frac{\sqrt[5]{\alpha} c_2 x \cdot {_1F_4}\left(\frac{\beta}{5\alpha}+\frac{1}{5};\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5},\frac{6}{5};-\frac{x^5 \alpha}{625}\right)}{5^{4/5}}+c_1\cdot {_1F_4}\left(\frac{\beta}{5\alpha};\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5};-\frac{x^5 \alpha}{625}\right)+\frac{\alpha^{4/5}c_5 x^4\cdot {_1F_4}\left(\frac{\beta}{5\alpha}+\frac{4}{5};\frac{6}{5},\frac{7}{5},\frac{8}{5},\frac{9}{5};-\frac{x^5 \alpha}{625}\right)}{\sqrt[5]{5}}+\frac{\alpha^{3/5} c_4 x^3\cdot {_1F_4}\left(\frac{\beta}{5\alpha}+\frac{3}{5};\frac{4}{5},\frac{6}{5},\frac{7}{5},\frac{8}{5};-\frac{x^5 \alpha}{625}\right)}{5^{2/5}}+\frac{\alpha^{2/5} c_3 x^2 {_1F_4}\left(\frac{\beta}{5\alpha}+\frac{2}{5};\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5},\frac{6}{5},\frac{7}{5};-\frac{x^5 \alpha}{625}\right)}{5^{3/5}}$$
If anyone is interested, here are the solutions for [$n=6$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27%27%27%27%2Ba*x*y%27%2Bb*y%3D0), [$n=7$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27%27%27%27%27%2Ba*x*y%27%2Bb*y%3D0), [$n=8$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27%27%27%27%27%27%2Ba*x*y%27%2Bb*y%3D0) and [$n=9$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27%27%27%27%27%27%27%2Ba*x*y%27%2Bb*y%3D0). I apologize if I mistyped one of the solutions.

As we can see, there is a pattern. I would therefore like to find a reason for this pattern.

---

**Here, I attempt to explain it using a power series solution:**

We make the ansatz:
$$y=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k x^k$$
Thus, if we substitute this into our ODE on $(2)$, we obtain:
$$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots (k-n+1)A_{k}x^{k-n}+\alpha\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k A_k x^{k}+\beta\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k x^k=0$$
Shifting the first sum, we obtain:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+n)(k+n-1)(k+n-2)\cdots (k+1)A_{k+n}x^{k}+\alpha\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k A_k x^{k}+\beta\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k x^k=0$$
Hence, we have:
$$\small n!\cdot A_n+\beta\cdot A_0+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (k+n)(k+n-1)(k+n-2)\cdots (k+1)A_{k+n}x^{k}+\alpha\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k A_k x^{k}+\beta\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k x^k=0$$
Thus, we obtain:
$$\small n!\cdot A_n+\beta\cdot A_0+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left[(k+n)(k+n-1)(k+n-2)\cdots (k+1)A_{k+n}+\alpha k A_k+\beta\cdot A_k\right]\cdot x^k=0$$
If the series is a solution, then all the coefficients must equal zero:
$$\begin{cases} A_n=-\frac{\beta}{n!}\cdot A_0 & k=0\\ A_{k+n}=-\frac{\alpha k+\beta}{(k+n)(k+n-1)(k+n-2)\cdots (k+1)}A_k &  k>0, k\in \mathbb{N}\end{cases}$$
The system of equations is redundant, thus one may just solve the following recurrence relation:
$$\small A_{k+n}=-\frac{\alpha k+\beta}{(k+n)(k+n-1)(k+n-2)\cdots (k+1)}A_k=-\frac{k!(\alpha k+\beta)}{(k+n)!}A_k=-\frac{\alpha k+\beta}{(k+1)_n} A_k \tag{4}$$
Where $(x)_n$ is the [Pochhammer Symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html).

The Hypergeometric function ${_1P_q}(a_1; b_1,\cdots,b_q;x)$ is [defined as](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html):
$${_1P_q}(a_1; b_1,\cdots,b_q;x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a_1)_k}{(b_1)_k\cdots (b_q)_k}\cdot \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
Given the recurrence, this should follow the pattern for general values of $n\geq 3, n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

---

**The problem:**

However, I am not satisfied with this. I would prefer if one could use one (or several) substitution(s) which works for general values of $n$ and which does not involve a series solution. My idea was to reduce the differential equation on $(2)$ to [Kummer's Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) to obtain these hypergeometric functions on their solutions:
$$z\frac{d^2 w}{dz^2}+(b-z)\frac{dw}{dz}-aw=0 \tag{5}$$
To do this, I've attempted to use the same substitution as done on my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2188299/solving-a-second-order-linear-ode-fracd2-ydx2x1-cdot-fracdydx):
$$\ln y=\ln{z}-\frac{(1+x)^2}{4}$$
However, the resulting ODE turns out to be even worse than it was previously (Even for $n=3$).

---

**The question:**

Is there any way we can make several substitutions such that we obtain the general solution for general values of $n$ where $n\geq 3, n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$?

If this is too difficult or not possible, is there a way we can use several substitutions for the specific case $n=3$ to obtain the general solution? i.e. The same one, or in a similar form to the one on equation $(3)$.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: my comment is coud we solve automatically for every 'n' ? i mean a complete formula $ f(x,n)$ which is valid for every 'n'

Comment: @JoseGarcia Not necessarily what I meant. What I am looking for is just a **series of substitutions** which works for general values of $n\geq 3$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. "A complete formula $f(x,n)$ which is valid for every $n$" would be answering my question (And would be even better), however keep in mind that I am not just looking for the answer, I would like to know how to get there. As I mentioned, if such is too difficult I'd be fine if one answers **just** the specific case of $n=3$ given by $(1)$, and then I can attempt something similar for the case of $n=4,5,\cdots$.

Comment: really your friend is all the way better than any of mine. :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define $s=-\frac{\alpha x^n}{n^{n-1}}$ and introduce Euler operators $\vartheta=s\frac{d}{ds}$ and $\delta=x\frac{d}{dx}=n\vartheta$.

**Lemma**. $x^n\frac{d^n}{dx^n}=\delta(\delta-1)(\delta-2)\ldots (\delta-n+1)$.

**Corollary 1**. $x^n\frac{d^n}{dx^n}=n^n\vartheta\left(\vartheta-\frac1n\right)\left(\vartheta-\frac2n\right)\ldots \left(\vartheta-\frac{n-1}n\right)$.

**Corollary 2**. After the change of independent variable $y(x)=f(s)$, the equation (2) becomes
$$\left[\vartheta\left(\vartheta-\frac1n\right)\left(\vartheta-\frac2n\right)\ldots \left(\vartheta-\frac{n-1}n\right)-s\left(\vartheta+\frac{\beta}{n\alpha}\right)\right]f(s)=0.$$
This is a particular case of the [standard form of the generalized hypergeometric equation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.8.E3) - namely, the equation for $_1F_{n-1}\left(\frac{\beta}{n\alpha};\frac1n,\ldots,\frac{n-1}{n};s\right)$. Other $n-1$ linear independent solutions can be chosen as in [formula 16.8.6 here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.8.E6).